# exception occurs when I want to retrieve data that is not present in the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I use JDBC to store my data in my SQL database. When I want to retrieve the data, it gives an exception. the code to retrieve the data is

```java
    public Stoke getCurrantStokeByBarcode(String barcode)
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM stoke WHERE barcode =?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,barcode);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.absolute(1);
            if (resultSet != null)
            {
                if (resultSet.getString(1).equals(barcode)) {
                    Stoke item = new Stoke(resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getString(4),
                            resultSet.getString(3),resultSet.getString(1)
                            ,resultSet.getString(5),resultSet.getString(7),
                            resultSet.getString(6),resultSet.getString(8)
                            ,resultSet.getString(9));
    
                    return item;
                }
            }
            else
                return null;
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I also included a check to for this exception, but it still occurs. How do I remove this exception?

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:780)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5204)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5127)
        at sample.Database.DatabaseHandler.getCurrantStokeByBarcode(DatabaseHandler.java:79)
        at sample.Controller.Add_StokeController.onBarcodeScan(Add_StokeController.java:218)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin reading from your result set or let the first row (if it exists) become your current row, you should first call [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()).

You may modify your code from

```java
if (resultSet != null)
```

to

```java
if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next())
```

as `next()` will return a `boolean` value indicating whether there is a row to be read. If there are no results then based on your existing logic the function will return null and not attempt to read from the empty result set.

Moreover, `resultSet.absolute(1);` is not required and I would recommend that you remove it.

Comment: The `resultSet != null` check is not necessary: `resultSet` will never be null, because `executeQuery` is required to throw a `SQLException` when called for a statement that does not produce a result set (a queries producing no rows has a result set, an empty result set).